# external jar file and class files are not getting add in jar file in nokia eclipse

Tags: eclipse, jar, java-me

External jar files and class files are not getting added into exported jar file in j2me project and they are not compiled while running the project and the project is failing in  pre-verifying.

Answer (score 0):

Check build path.
Right click on project >  properties > Build path.
Add jars as neded.

Comment: I have  added as u said but its giving error like "Error preverifying  class.  What i have to do this??